# Please help me write the value in the database

Tags: php

There is a script which pings all the ip addresses in the column "ip_address", I need to ping after reports he wrote in the column "status". I.e. If the computer is online, in the column "status" write the value 1, if the offline database set to 0. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTiAT.jpg

He does not want to write this value. Here's my script:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.10.56", "test", "test", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Failed to connect: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 1 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE 'test' SET 'status'='1' WHERE ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'");
     }else{ 
        $insert_sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE 'test' SET 'status'='0' WHERE ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'");
}
    }

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

How to write a value `mysqli_query` correctly?

Comment: What is `$test`, and from where do you get it? And if it's an array of all IP-adresses, then the `$value` of it will be an IP, so you won't have to do `$value->ip_address`, but can do just `$value` instead.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** If you're going to make a minimal example, please add some comment lines on your code, explaining the origin of variables that are not shown in the scope.

Comment: u_mulder, where should I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Yoou can put var_dump after exec("ping -c 1 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);

var_dump($output);

var_dump($result);

Where $result is return variable. 
You query seems fine.
you can also refer at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for command line execution.